# Insert dot after each words in string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to realize method, which accept string and insert a dot (.) after each word. example:

Source string: "Hello! It is nice day today."

Result string: "Hello!. It. is. nice. day. today.."

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotted = string.Join(". ","Hello! It is nice day today.".Split(' ')) + ".";
```

this should work, but the other 2 answers should get you pretty close.

Comment: I have just comment my solution suggesting to append a dot at the end

Answer (score 5):

For the most part you can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
var dotted = "Your string".Replace(" ", ". ");
```

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

I'm sure you can elaborate from here to get your trailing period/any other nuances you find. (:

Comment: This wont work under all condition. It wont add for the last word of the sentence, and will add the dot after comma, and not after the word before the comma.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen _'I'm sure you can elaborate from here to get your trailing period.'_

Comment: If my source string is: "Hello(three space)It(two space)" your method returns: "Hello. . . . It. . ". It omits words at all.

Comment: @Praetor12 While I like to help, sometimes teaching someone to fish is best - you can use the `Replace` method (among others) to manipulate strings accordingly, so while this might not be perfect (you didn't give a 'perfect' example anyway), it should suffice for you to build on, should you aspire to do so.

Answer (score 4):

```
string.Join(".","Hello! It is nice day today.".Split(' '));
```

Comment: This wont work under all condition. It wont add for the last word of the sentence, and will add the dot after comma, and not after the word before the comma.

Comment: Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen is right. This simple solution is not work under all conditions.

Comment: this is the result: Hello!.It.is.nice.day.today..
my idea was just give an idea on how to implement it it is not a full version.if you append a string empty at the end it will work

Comment: @Praetor12 - "all conditions" is pretty vague. You should probably update your question describing all the conditions.

Comment: But if `!.` and `..` are OK why isn't `,.`

Comment: if by requirement the last work does not have an empty space you can just append one "." at the end.Anyway It's just a generic way to do that it si not a complete solution which has to be shaped around the requirements